# What language was RabbitMQ written in?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm looking at the repos and there are so many projects, not sure which are wrappers/clients and which is the actual project.

Is it Erlang?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is Erlang. You can check this out by downloading the source for the server here:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v2.3.1/

Answer (score 3):

See [Wikipedia: RabbitMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ)

> > **The RabbitMQ server is written in Erlang** and is built on the Open Telecom Platform framework for clustering and failover.

The actual documentation/promo on http://rabbitmq.com is rather fluffy ;-)